# Heap.m data structure package in Mathematica (Book: Computer Science with Mathematica, CUP press)

Tags: data-structures

The CUP press book *Computer Science with Mathematica* discusses heaps in section 8.4.3.

The package Heap.m is mentioned (for import), containing functions such as HeapPlot.

Can you advise where to find such packages and Heap.m in particular? I realise that the .m format may be obsolete. Perhaps an update exists?

Comment: If you have not already seen https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1425074 then I suggest you read all that very carefully

Comment: Thanks Bill, that is very helpful.

Comment: Depending on whether your goal is to implement a Heap yourself (as a learning exercise) or to use a heap you might also consider the new DataStructures work in recent Mathematica 12.x releases. Specifically PriorityQueue is a heap: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/PriorityQueue.html (including visualization too)

Comment: The `.m` format is not obsolete. To be accurate, there is no "`.m` format", only an `.m` file extension. `.m` files are plain text files that contain Wolfram Language code. While Wolfram seems to recommend the `.wl` extension recently, the contents of the files are exactly the same (and also: the `.m` extension is still recognized). All that said, the Wolfram Language has changed throughout the years, and old packages may not work without modification.

Comment: I do not know where to find this file, but have a look at: "https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4378/" or in the help "guide/DataStructures"

Comment: In addition to the PriorityQueue data structure built into recent versions, there is a reference implementation in the Wolfram Function Repository [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PriorityQueue/).

Comment: Thanks all, super helpful. Should have thought to check on PriorityQueues.